# TypeError: runfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_namespace'

Tags: python, debugging

I got the error message when trying to debug a python script:

```
debugfile('C:/Users/Wei-shan/Desktop/pythonScripts/simple pendulum.py', wdir='C:/Users/Wei-shan/Desktop/pythonScripts', current_namespace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Wei-shan\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19384/837447315.py", line 1, in <module>
    debugfile('C:/Users/Wei-shan/Desktop/pythonScripts/simple pendulum.py', wdir='C:/Users/Wei-shan/Desktop/pythonScripts', current_namespace=True)

  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 589, in debugfile
    enter_debugger(

  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 773, in enter_debugger
    debugger.run(code)

  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 716, in run
    super(SpyderPdb, self).run(cmd, globals, locals)

  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\bdb.py", line 580, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: runfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_namespace'
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you very much

Comment: I have the same issue with spyder and I am looking for a solution too. I would recommend to add a small script that can reproduce this issue and also add the tag "spyder" to this question since it is related to this IDE.

Answer (score 19):

This [will be fixed](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16316) in Spyder 5.1.2. In the meantime, downgrade the `ipykernel` package in the environment to 6.2.0:

```sh
conda activate my_env
conda install ipykernel=6.2.0
```

You should see something like:

```sh
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  ipykernel                            6.4.1-py37h06a4308_1 --> 6.2.0-py37h06a4308_1
```

after which, restart spyder and it should be good.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the error was fixed by completely uninstalling and reinstalling Spyder. It looks like the problem is that you have an outdated version of the spyder kernels. There was a change some time ago [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-kernels/pull/150/commits/afed07825f514bf781bfde18d3173d9cc86e71a9). Maybe a simple

```
conda update --all
```

is enough. But i haven't tested this.

Comment: I tried `conda update --all`, and it did not work...